# Scatterplot in R Shiny that is interactive with a variable that isn't the x or y axis

Tags: r, shiny

I'm not 100% sure how to properly ask this question, but the problem I am hoping to solve should be pretty straightforward.

I am interested in making an interactive scatterplot in R Shiny that changes not based on selecting a new value for either the x or y axis, but from another variable in the dataset.

Specifically, I am looking to plot revenue (y axis) for a given team from 1998-2019 (x axis) and would like to be able to change which team is being shown. Currently, every team is shown at once, which makes the graph difficult to understand. I don't want the x axis or y axis to change, just which data points are being shown that correspond to a singular team each time.

The code I have used, which results in a non-interactive graph showing every data point at once, is as follows:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
         titlePanel("Concede-and-Divide Rule Allocation 1998-2019"),
         sidebarLayout(  
         sidebarPanel(
             #option for selecting teams
          selectInput(
            "HmTm", "Home Team:",
            choices=same_team$HmTm
          ),
           ),
         mainPanel(
           plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")
         )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(same_team, aes(x = year, y = Concede_and_Divide_Revenue, color = HmTm)) + 
      geom_point() + xlab("Year") + ylab("Concede-and-Divide Allocation") + 
      ggtitle("Concede-and-Divide Rule Allocation 1998-2019") + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, hjust=1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to subset the data frame that you are plotting.  Try this

```
library(gapminder)

same_team <- gapminder[gapminder$continent=="Americas",]
same_team$HmTm <- same_team$country
same_team$Concede_and_Divide_Revenue <- same_team$gdpPercap

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Concede-and-Divide Rule Allocation 1998-2019"),
  sidebarLayout(  
    sidebarPanel(
      #option for selecting teams
      selectInput(
        "HmTm", "Home Team:",
        choices= unique(same_team$HmTm)
      ),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")
    )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(same_team[same_team$HmTm==input$HmTm,], aes(x = year, y = Concede_and_Divide_Revenue, color = HmTm)) + 
      geom_point() + xlab("Year") + ylab("Concede-and-Divide Allocation") + 
      ggtitle("Concede-and-Divide Rule Allocation 1998-2019") + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, hjust=1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]